# Is ther a way in R and modelsummary to stack a comparisons table produced by marginal effects

Tags: r, modelsummary, r-marginaleffects

I ran several linear regressions and  obtained comparisons from the `avg_comparisons` function of the `marginaleffects` package and then form it with the `shape = term : contrast ~ model` option parameters of the `modelsummary` package to concatenate the term and contrast. This results in the desired first part of the table. Now I wanted to make two panels and stacked them.
With standard regressions this works very fine with the `shape = "rbind"` function, but not when I need to concatenate term and contrast before.
Is there a way in the syntax of the `shape` option that allows to combine this two different behaviors? Or is there another way of achieving the stacking of the panels?

I ran the following code to produce the comparisons

```
vars <- c("var1", "var2", "var3")

panel1 <- vars %>%
    paste(., "~ Treatment") %>%
    map(as.formula) %>%
    map(lm, data = df) %>% 
    map(avg_comparisons, variables = "Treatment", vcov = "hc1") 
modelsummary(panel1, shape = term : contrast ~ model)
```

this produced the desired outcome for one panel. Then I tried to add another panel

```
vars <- c("var4", "var5")

panel2 <- vars2 %>%
    paste(., "~ Treatment") %>%
    map(as.formula) %>%
    map(lm, data = df) %>% 
    map(avg_comparisons, variables = "Treatment", vcov = "hc1") 

panels(list(panel1, panel2))

modelsummary(panels, shape = term : contrast ~ model)
```

This produced an error, as `modelsummary` does not accept the inputs as list, when `shape` is not "rbind".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I can't think of a completely automatic way to do this right now. What you could do is proceed in steps: Create an intermediate representation in `modelsummary_list` format, combine the labels, and feed the result back to `modelsummary`. Example:

```
library(modelsummary)
library(marginaleffects)

# fit
mod <- list(
  lm(mpg ~ am + factor(cyl), data = mtcars),
  lm(mpg ~ hp + am + factor(cyl), data = mtcars)
)

mod <- lapply(mod, avg_comparisons)

# intermediate representation
tab <- modelsummary(mod, output = "modelsummary_list")

# combine labels
tab[[1]]$tidy$term <- paste(tab[[1]]$tidy$term, tab[[1]]$tidy$contrast)
tab[[2]]$tidy$term <- paste(tab[[2]]$tidy$term, tab[[2]]$tidy$contrast)

# back to modelsummary
modelsummary(tab, shape = "rbind", gof_map = "nobs")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have transformed @Vincent s answer into a function, to automatize a bit more.

```
transform_comparison_contr_treat <- function(comparison) {
    map(comparison, ~ {
        .x$tidy$term <- paste(
            paste(.x$tidy$term, .x$tidy$contrast),
            .x$tidy$TreatmentJob
        )
        return(.x)
    })
}
```

Comment: I figured out that there is also the possibility to concatenate using the shape function , `shape = term:contrast ~ model` , and using the `output = "modelsummary_list" `` function. This saves the paste operation. I think it would be great to enhance the shape function allowing to concatenate several columns into one, at the moment it seems that it handles only two.